# react axios post generates json in array format. How to convert this to "name":"value" type format

Tags: json, reactjs, post, axios

[image]

```
        const submitService = {
        serviceType: this.state.serviceType,
        dateOfService: this.state.dateOfService,
        vehicleId: this.state.vehicleId,            
        orderNum: this.state.orderNum,
        driverId: this.state.driverId,
        vendorName: this.state.vendorName,
        issueId: this.state.issueId
    };

    axios.post("http://localhost:8072/TruckyServiceMicroService/admin/services/saveService/", submitService)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data != null) {
                this.setState(this.initialState);
                alert("Service Created Successfully");
            }

        });
```

This is the const forming the json and the post request sent using the const. On sending the post request through axios, it adds square braces in the json

```
    initialState = {
    serviceType: [], vehicleId: '', dateOfService: '', orderNum: '', driverId: '', vendorName: '', issueId: ''
}
```

This is the state

Comment: What does your state look like?

Comment: You are not sending a json, but a raw JavaScript object. In the second argument in your post method, instead of passing `submitService` try passing `JSON.stringify(submitService)`

Comment: @Ryan {"servicetype":["3"],"dateOfService":["2020-06-02"],"vehicleId":["343"],"orderNum":["demo123"],"driverId":["driver1"],"vendorName":["dineshtest"],"issueId":["issue1"]}:

It is still including the square braces

Comment: @user0101     initialState = {
        serviceType: [], vehicleId: '', dateOfService: '', orderNum: '', driverId: '', vendorName: '', issueId: ''
    }

Comment: could you log `submitService` just before sending the post?

Comment: @Ryan
{servicetype: Array(1), dateOfService: Array(1), vehicleId: Array(1), orderNum: Array(1), driverId: Array(1), …}
dateOfService: ["2020-06-03"]
driverId: ["driver1"]
issueId: ["issue1"]

Comment: it looks like every value in that object is an array? wrapping it in square braces would be expected. you need to debug to understand why each value is an array, since it appears you set the initial state as empty strings. but clearly that is not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a quick fix, change:

```
const submitService = {
    serviceType: this.state.serviceType,
    dateOfService: this.state.dateOfService,
    vehicleId: this.state.vehicleId,            
    orderNum: this.state.orderNum,
    driverId: this.state.driverId,
    vendorName: this.state.vendorName,
    issueId: this.state.issueId
};
```

to:

```
const keys = ["serviceType","dateOfService","vehicleId","orderNum","driverId","vendorName","issueId"]
const submitService = Object.entries(this.state).reduce((res, ([key, val])) => {
    if(keys.includes(key))
      res[key] = Array.isArray(val)?val[0]:val
    return res
}, {})
```

this basically creates the payload with keys and values pairs of state but if the value is array type it just uses the first index of it.

Comment: Thanks, but getting error   'res' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: this answer is an extremely 'hacky' approach and should be used with extreme caution... but glad it fixes the problem for you for now.